# Discord js and Minecraft server util

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot with the command `!mc (server-ip)`. Then it replies with an embed and it show the server IP, online players etc. I have not yet tried any code because I couldn't find it for Discord V14.

Does anyone know where I can find this or have an example of this?

Comment: Look through the guides and construct your own code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the Discord bot I simply invite you to read the Discord.js  documentation that you can find here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.5.0/general/welcome

As for the Minecraft part, you can use [this API](https://mcapi.us/) which allows you to obtain some information from an IP address.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).